# Why is my website's navigation stuck to the top center of the screen?

Tags: html, css, layout, shopify, liquid

As you can see, the container (image + nav) is stuck to the top of the screen. [Image stuck to top of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTvLx.png)
-- the attached image is a link to imgur

I've tried changing the position type, trying flex, and "top" with css.

here's a snippet:
As you can see by the screenshot, the navigation on my screen is stuck to the top of the screen.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: IDIDNTSTEALTHIS;
  src: url(https://static.wixstatic.com/ufonts/617a47_069dbc8c08b34b95bda387f5d2f9b534/woff2/file.woff2);
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  font-family: IDIDNTSTEALTHIS;
}

header#SiteHeader {
  display: none;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.btm-nav {
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.btm-nav i {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.btm-nav h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: IDIDNTSTEALTHIS;
  margin: -2px 0px 0px;
}

a,
:active,
:hover,
:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.context-menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu-button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #3E3E3E;
}

.social-media-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.social-media-button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #0B0B0B;
  margin-right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: calc(25% - 1px);
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.social-media-button:hover {
  background-color: #363636;
}

.social-media-button i {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.social-media-button i {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

i.fa-brands.fa-discord {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.btm-nav-1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}

.btm-nav-1 {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.btm-nav-2 {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.btm-nav-3 {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.btm-nav-4 {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.logo-container img {
  max-width: 134px;
  max-height: 89%;
}

.btm-nav-1,
.btm-nav-2,
.btm-nav-3,
.btm-nav-4,
.btm-nav-5 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 0.05px solid #FFF;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 134px;
  height: 20px;
}

.btm-nav-1:hover,
.btm-nav-2:hover,
.btm-nav-3:hover,
.btm-nav-4:hover,
.btm-nav-5:hover {
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}

.social-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.social-link {
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <img class="syn-img" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0651/1683/1959/files/NEW-LOGO.png?v=1686555777" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="btm-nav">
      <div class="btm-nav-1">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <h1>BUTTON</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="btm-nav-2">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <h1>BUTTON</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="btm-nav-3">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <h1>BUTTON</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="btm-nav-4">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <h1>BUTTON</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="btm-nav-5">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <h1>BUTTON</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="social-nav">
        <div class="social-link discordLink">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-discord" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="social-link instagramLink">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="social-link twitterLink">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="social-link tiktokLink">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by stuck?

Comment: @imvain2 By stuck I just mean It's at the top of the screen and I have no idea why. I checked the css and I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: The snippet looks perfectly fine, but on my website the nav is all messed up and weird... The website is https://grimlabs.co. if it gives you a "password" page, click the lock icon and enter the password "tonythetiger"

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to present enough information _in your question_ so we can see the problem. Links to your website aren't adequate.

Comment: I think this comes down to terminology. There is a method called making something sticky, which sticks to the top or bottom for example. However, what you actually want is to have your content vertically centered on the page.

Answer (score 0):

To display the image and nav in the center, update the styles of the body to this:

```
body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
 }
```

```css
@font-face {
        font-family: IDIDNTSTEALTHIS;
        src: url(https://static.wixstatic.com/ufonts/617a47_069dbc8c08b34b95bda387f5d2f9b534/woff2/file.woff2);
    }

    html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: black;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        font-family: IDIDNTSTEALTHIS;
    }

    header#SiteHeader {
        display: none;
    }

    body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .logo-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }

    .btm-nav {
        width: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .btm-nav i {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: white;
        padding-top: 1px;
    }

    .btm-nav h1 {
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-family: IDIDNTSTEALTHIS;
        margin: -2px 0px 0px;
    }

    a,
    :active,
    :hover,
    :visited {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .context-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu-button {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
        background-color: #000000;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 25px;
        transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .menu-button:hover {
        background-color: #3E3E3E;
    }

    .social-media-buttons {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .social-media-button {
        flex-grow: 1;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #0B0B0B;
        margin-right: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: calc(25% - 1px);
        border: 1px solid #cecece;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-left: 2px;
    }

    .social-media-button:hover {
        background-color: #363636;
    }

    .social-media-button i {
        font-size: 15px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .social-media-button i {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    i.fa-brands.fa-discord {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .btm-nav-1 {
        border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    }

    .btm-nav-1 {
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    }

    .btm-nav-2 {
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    }

    .btm-nav-3 {
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    }

    .btm-nav-4 {
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    }

    .logo-container img {
        max-width: 134px;
        max-height: 89%;
    }

    .btm-nav-1,
    .btm-nav-2,
    .btm-nav-3,
    .btm-nav-4,
    .btm-nav-5 {
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin: 5px;
        background-color: #000;
        border: 0.05px solid #FFF;
        padding: 1px;
        width: 134px;
        height: 20px;
    }

    .btm-nav-1:hover,
    .btm-nav-2:hover,
    .btm-nav-3:hover,
    .btm-nav-4:hover,
    .btm-nav-5:hover {
        border: 2px solid #FFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .social-nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
        margin-top: 12px;
    }

    .social-link {
        margin: 0px 5px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'home.css' | asset_url }}">
    <script async src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/56070a7eed.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo-container">
             <img class="syn-img" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0651/1683/1959/files/NEW-LOGO.png?v=1686555777" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="btm-nav">
    <div class="btm-nav-1">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <h1>BUTTON</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
   <div class="btm-nav-2">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <h1>BUTTON</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
   <div class="btm-nav-3">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <h1>BUTTON</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btm-nav-4">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <h1>BUTTON</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
  <div class="btm-nav-5">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <h1>BUTTON</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="social-nav">
    <div class="social-link discordLink">
      <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-discord" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
      
    <div class="social-link instagramLink">
     <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
         
    <div class="social-link twitterLink">
      <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
        
    <div class="social-link tiktokLink">
      <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    </div>
         
  </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```